# Hard time with tables in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to create a table that will calculate the power factor (e.g. 4<sup>3</sup>) based on a number entered.

For example, if I enter 4, it will create 4 rows of results starting from 1 and ending with 64 or if I enter 6, it will create 6 rows of results starting from 1 and ending with 216.

I'm also trying to create the columns with specific headers but they don't line up with the numbers.  For example:  `x   x^2   x^3` would be the headers but the numbers don't align underneath it properly.

Currently, I seem to be getting calculations for the number entered but only that number.  Additionally, it is printing it 8 times and I don't know why.

I also can't seem to figure out how to repeat the loop.  For instance, if I were to enter 11 (outside of my parameters) I have a message but don't know how to loop back to the top to try again.  Please help!

The following is what I have thus far:

```
{
    int x;
    int y = 10;
    int rows;
    int columns;

    NSLog(@"Enter your number: ");
    scanf("%i", &x);

    {
        NSLog(@"x x^2 x^3");

        for (rows = 0; rows <= 1; rows++)
        {
            for (columns = 1; columns <= 3; columns++)
            {
                if (x < y)
                    NSLog(@"%d %d %d", x, x*x, x*x*x);
                else
                    NSLog(@"You are wrong!");
            }
        }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop and output are wrong. You're looping over at most two `rows`:

```
for (rows = 0; rows <= 1; rows++)
```

According to your question, you want to loop over `x` rows:

```
for (rows = 0; rows < x; rows++)
```

You have a loop for `columns`, but are printing out your line all at once with an `NSLog`.

```
for (rows = 1; rows <= x; rows++) {
  NSLog(@"%d %d %d", rows, rows*rows, rows*rows*rows);
}
```

Now you'll just have to use your format flags correctly to get your spacing right for the columns.

```
NSLog(@"         x        x^2        x^3");
for (rows = 1; rows <= x; rows++) {
  NSLog(@"%10d %10d %10d", rows, rows*rows, rows*rows*rows);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ian!  That solves my calculation and table problem!  I can tweek the columns.  I do have another question though, it does not seem to terminate if I enter 11 or higher.  I tried an if else statement but get an error with else saying "expected expression."  I'm probably missing something quite small.  One last thing, how would I send the program back into the loop if an 11 or higher is entered?